# Invalid syntax error on "def" in my coding.

Tags: python

Here is my code: I'm not sure what the problem is. It says invalid syntax on "def sub". I've looked everywhere and as far as I can tell, it is properly formatted for python 3

```
def add():
        print ("Enter the two numbers to Add")
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B: "))
        return A + B 

def sub():
        print ("Enter the two numbers to Subtract")
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B: "))
        return A - B

def mul():
        print ("Enter the two numbers to Multiply")
        A=int(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=int(raw_input("Enter B: "))
    return A * B

def div():
        print ("Enter the two number to Divide")
        A=float(raw_input("Enter A: "))
        B=float(raw_input("Enter B: "))
        return A / B

print ("1: ADD")
print ("2: SUBTRACT")
print ("3: MULTIPLY")
print ("4: DIVIDE")
print ("0: QUIT")

while True:

    CHOICE = int(raw_input("ENTER THE CORRESPONDING NUMBER FOR CALCULATION ")) 

    if CHOICE == 1: 
        print ('ADD TWO NUMBERS:')
        print add()

    elif CHOICE == 2:
        print ('SUBTRACT TWO NUMBERS')
        print sub()

    elif CHOICE == 3:
        print ('MULTIPLY TWO NUMBERS')
        print mul()

    elif CHOICE == 4:
        print ("DIVIDE TWO NUMBERS")
        print div()

    elif CHOICE == 0:
        exit()
    else:
        print ("The value Enter value from 1-4")
```

Comment: you should unnaccept that edit, and edit the code yourself. I can almost garuntee that this error is SOMEWHERe where you tabbed too much or not enough, also the person who edited messed up the `return` line in `mul()` and you might not immediately see what you did wrong if someone else edits it.

Comment: You are mixing 8-space indentation and 4-space indentation

Comment: My bad. I rolled back my edit.

Comment: @Josh: please properly format your code so that the question shows in the gray box what you see in your text editor

Comment: It's nothing wrong with your code.
It works fine by me, but I can test it on 2.7 only.

Comment: If you are really using Python 3, you'll get name errors for all those `raw_input()` function calls.

Comment: @GyörgySolymosi: that doesn't mean it'll work on Python 3, by a long shot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, but the only thing I wanted to obtain for help, that the code works as a script structure.

Answer (score 2):

All the prints like:

```
print add()
```

are missing the parenthesis. They should be:

```
print(add())
```

Same for all the prints

Comment: @ drol No need of  parenthesis

Comment: He says that he wants to use python3, then yes you do need them

Comment: I'm a little tied up at the moment; can't edit it right now. But I'd like to thank everyone for responding, hopefully it works. THANK YOU so much!